# How to parallelize function call in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have this code:

```
fog_coeff = [0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0]
start = time.time()
for f in fog_coeff:

    foggy_images= am.add_fog(images[0:278],fog_coeff=f)

    for img in foggy_images:
        im = Image.fromarray(img)
        im.save('./result/'+str(counter)+'-'+str(fog_coeff)+'.jpg')
        counter += 1
print("time taken"+ str(time.time()-start))
```

I want to parallize this. How can I do this? My main idea was to take each value from fog_coeff list and give it to each core. Each core will then process 278 images. Is this the right direction? If so, how can I proceed?

Comment: Have a look at the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) library.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options for this, `Thread`s or `Process`es. The first are allowed to share memory but they are limited in what they can do concurrently, so you can use variables to share the results for example, but you will have to use locks to avoid fdata races.

On the other side processes do not allow to share memory, gaining full concurrency at the OS level. You will have to use some sort of external communication like sockets to send the output back to the main process, or write their results to files.

The answer would depend on which of these two mechanisms you choose.

Edit: elaborating multi processing.

This is done with the `multiprocessing` library. You will basically define the function that you want your other process to run and then run it in a different process. Processes are handled by the OS, not by Python, so your OS scheduler will be in charge of where each process can be executed. There are advanced tools like process pools that would allow you to have always 4 processes running (in case you are on a quadra-core) but you won't be able to tell your OS how should he handle those processes. He may want to execute its own background processes.

Comment: Please elaborate second one

Comment: Python documentation does a better job than me providing examples: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: More exactly, use `Pool()`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool

The default number of processes is already the number of CPU cores

Comment: @maestro.inc Threads are concurrent, and they may be parallel depending on which Python implementation you are using. You were refering to the GIL, weren't you? GIL is implementation-dependant.